# RenderUI for both table and plot?

Tags: r

I have somehow tried to make an application to extract all stocks data. The below code is working. But, at the last, there are radio buttons like shown below. So when I click the radiobuttons (All, Open, Close, High and Low), the ggplot should appear for a particular company. I have also written the code also.

For example. When I click "All", the ggplot for Open, High, Close and Low should appear. But when I select Open, the plot should be only for Open. Hope I am making sense. The code is almost fine, But when I click the radio buttons, the plot is not getting displayed.

[image]

````
---
output$t10 <- renderPlot({
    if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S)){
       asd1 <- input$C
       days <- input$S
       as2 <- tq_get(asd1, from = Sys.Date()-days, to = Sys.Date())
       as2 <- as.data.frame(as2)
       as21 <- as2[c(1:5)]
       as2_melt <- melt(as2,id=c("date"))
       plot_data <- as2_melt
    } 
    if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 == "All")
    {
      plot_data <- plot_data
    }
    if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 != "All")
    {
      plot_data <- plot_data %>% filter(variable %in% input$R12)
    }
    if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 == "All")
    {
      ggplot(data = plot_data,aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_line(size=0.2)
    }
    if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 != "All")
    {
      ggplot(data = plot_data,aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_line(size=0.2)
    }
})

output$filter_70 <- renderUI(
  if (input$R == "Individual Company") {
  dataTableOutput("table1")
} else if (input$R == "Multiple Companies") {
  dataTableOutput("table12")
} else if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 == "All"){
  plotOutput("t10")
}
)
uiOutput("filter_70")
```
````

Comment: Is it possible to reduce it down just to the plot part? Also, to prevent unnecessary issues with DT output when you upgrade `shiny`, call `render*` and `data*` explicitly i.e. `DT::render*` and `DT::data*`

Comment: I did not get you. Could you please come again. Is there any issue with the code here?

Comment: The issue is that we don't want to wade through 150 lines of code, esp when (as I suspect) this is likely nothing to do with `shiny`, just logical selection.

Comment: Cool. May I know which part of code you need? Please

Comment: @DevP see https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2653. Just the part necessary to run the App and get the plot, as we can't go through the entire code and understand all these parameters.

Comment: I have edited...

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

In `plot_data`, `variable` values are in small letters i.e. open, colse, ... etc, while `input$R12` is in capital letter therefore `plot_data %>% filter(variable %in% input$R12)` endup with 0 observations. to solve this chnage `choices` to `choices = c("All"="All","Open"="open","Close"="close","High"="high","Low"="low")`

**Full answer**

- Add some `print`s for debugging
- Add `req` to prevent initialization errors
- Add placeholder varibale `p` for `ggplot` and redesign `filter_70`

````
---
title: "Stock Analysis"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
vertical_layout: scroll
theme: united
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyquant)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r}
Ticker <- data.frame(Ticker = c("1STCUS.BO","21STCENMGM.BO"))
Ticker <- as.data.frame(Ticker)
```

Company Daily Stocks
=================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}
radioButtons("R","Parameters",choices = c("Individual Company","Multiple Companies"),selected = character(0),inline = F)
output$filter1 <- renderUI({
  req(input$R)
  if(input$R == "Individual Company"){
    label = "Company"
    selectInput("C",label,choices = c("",levels(factor(Ticker$Ticker))))
  } else if(input$R == "Multiple Companies"){
    label = "Companies"
    selectInput("C1",label,choices = c("",levels(factor(Ticker$Ticker))),multiple = TRUE)
  }
})
uiOutput("filter1")

actionButton("A","Execute",icon = NULL)

output$filter2 <- renderUI({
  req(input$R)
  if(input$R == "Individual Company"){
    label = "Since No of days"
    sliderInput("S",label,min = 1,max = 100,value = 10)
  } else if(input$R == "Multiple Companies"){
    label = "Since No of days"
    sliderInput("S1",label,min = 1,max = 10,value = 10)
  }
})
uiOutput("filter2")


output$filter3 <- renderUI({
  req(input$R)
  if(input$R == "Individual Company"){
    label = "Open-Close-High-Low"
    radioButtons("R12",label,choices = c("All"="All","Open"="open","Close"="close","High"="high","Low"="low"),selected = character(0),inline = F)
  } else if(input$R == "Multiple Companies"){
    label = "Segments"
    radioButtons("R12",label,choices = c("Open"="open","Close"="close","High"="high"),selected = character(0),inline = T)
  }
})

uiOutput("filter3")
```

Column {data-height=7000}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Stocks Table

```{r}

output$t10 <- renderPlot({
   req(input$C)
   req(input$S)
   req(input$R12)
  if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S)){
    asd1 <- input$C
    days <- input$S
    as2 <- tq_get(asd1, from = Sys.Date()-days, to = Sys.Date())
    as2 <- as.data.frame(as2)
    as21 <- as2[c(1:5)]
    as2_melt <- data.table::melt(as2,id=c("date"))
    plot_data <- as2_melt
  } 
  if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 == "All")
  {
    plot_data <- plot_data
  }
  if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 != "All")
  { #For debugging
    print(input$R12)
    print(table(plot_data$variable))
    print(head(plot_data))

    plot_data <- plot_data %>% filter(variable %in% input$R12)
  }
  if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 == "All")
  {
    p <- ggplot(data = plot_data,aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_line(size=0.2)
  }
  if (!is.null(input$C) && !is.null(input$S) && input$R12 != "All")
  {
    p <- ggplot(data = plot_data,aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_line(size=0.2)
  }
  p
})

output$filter_70 <- renderUI({
  req(input$R)
if (input$R == "Individual Company") {
  dataTableOutput("table1")
  plotOutput("t10")
} else if (input$R == "Multiple Companies") {
  dataTableOutput("table12")
  plotOutput("t10")
}

})
uiOutput("filter_70")
```
````

Comment: Thanks. May I know why ````req```` is used?

Comment: you're welcome. for `req` see documentation by typing `?req` in R console.